# How can i build this json format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json where the values will be passed dynamically in javascript,

```
{
  "User": {
    "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "memNum": "70000211981",
    "orderslist": [
      {
        "orderid": "5119534",
        "ordersource": "ONLINE",
        "transactiondttm": "2014-01-09"
      },
      {
        "orderid": "5119534",
        "ordersource": "STORE",
        "transactiondttm": "2014-01-09"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and i tried using this function to build the json but it doesnt seem to work,

```
function addOrder(req, orderId, orderSource, transactiondtm) {
    req.User.orderslist.orderid.push(orderId);
    req.User.orderslist.ordersource.push(orderSource);
    req.User.orderslist.transactiondtm.push(transactiondtm);
}
```

Any suggestion..

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: 10.5k rep, and still describes a problem as "it doesn't seem to work"...

Comment: Please show how you call that function. (Is the first argument an object that already has a `User` property that is itself an object with an `orderslist` array?)

Answer (score 1):

The elements of `orderslist` are objects, not arrays, so you can't `push` onto them. You have to build them as objects, and then push that onto the `orderslist` array.

```
function addOrder(req, orderId, orderSource, transactiondtm) {
    req.User.orderslist.push({ orderid: orderId,
                               ordersource: orderSource,
                               transactiondtm: transactiondtm });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
function addOrder(req, orderId, orderSource, transactiondtm) {
    req.User.orderslist.push({
        "orderid": orderId,
        "ordersource": orderSource,
        "transactiondtm": transactiondtm
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects can be acessed like an array.
That way you can create dinamic members.

```
user = {"orderList":[]};

for(var i = 0; i<5; i++){
    user.orderList[i] = {};
    user.orderList[i]["orderId"] = i;
    user.orderList[i]["orderSource"] = "STORE";
}

alert(user.orderList[0].orderSource);
//Shows "STORE"
```

you can see the code working here http://jsfiddle.net/wmgE6/